# How to create a Microsoft teams tab app with VueJS framework

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-teams-js

I am trying to set up a teams app with VueJS, since my project is built on top of it.

I have tried to create a teams app with visual studio and add vuejs into it. But this dosent work with components and import fails to work.  - Here Teams works fine, Vuejs fails

After some more research came across this post CREATE CUSTOM WEB APPS FOR MICROSOFT TEAMS USING AZURE FUNCTION, NODE JS. - Here VueJS works fine. seem like i can test teams part only after setting up azure static site.  I tried to build it and upload as custom app, throws error on upload.

Is it possible to test in local (uploading custom apps to teams app?)   Or setting up azure static site the way to go , for teams app development

Comment: Missed the URL . its https://sibeeshpassion.com/create-custom-web-apps-for-microsoft-teams-using-azure-function-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, its just the set of manifest and icon files, that define teams app.
Adding them to a project and updating params should work.